# Change background and font colour in mac terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

Is it possible to change the colour of the background on the terminal window from the default white?

Also, can it be changed after the terminal window has been created?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With terminal open, in the top menu, select Terminal => Preferences => Settings.

You can change to a number of color combos:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Terminal -> Preferences -> Settings